# Session logout not working

Tags: php

```
 session_start();  
 ob_start();   
 unset($_SESSION);  
 session_destroy();  
 header("Location:login.php");
```

Even after logout from home page session didn't destroy
inner pages redirection is working after logout. please help me

Comment: Try `print_r($_SESSION);` on the pages and see if the session is set after you log out.

Comment: From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php): **Caution**
Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.

Comment: Just, session_start() and session_destroy(); should do the trick?

Comment: have you validated the session value in every page ? post that too.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to only do a session_destroy right after you do session_start. Do not unset the whole variable, this also disables the registration of session variables.

```
 session_start();
 ..
 session_destroy();  
 header("Location: login.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `session_unset` instead of unset($_SESSION):

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destory();
header("Location:login.php"); 
?>
```